# Best way to create a Facebook Follow button on nodes

Tags: social-network

I have some nodes with information about a political candidate. Some of the candidates have a Facebook profile, which I link to using an URL-field.

But they also want a follow button directly on the page. I was thinking of typing in their handle to a text field and create a field formatter to render the code for the actual button.

Is this the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

[Facebook Subscribe Button](https://drupal.org/project/facebook_subscribe)

> This module will automatically add the Facebook code for Facebook
>   Subscribe button which will be displayed in the block and each page
>   node.

[image]

> - Administrators can also control which content type(s) the Facebook Subscribe button will or won't appear on, as well as which role(s) are
>     allowed to view the button (regardless of whether or not the user is
>     logged into Facebook at the time).
> - Along with a Subscribe button appearing for each node, there is an optional block that can be set to appear on each page.
> - By default, the button will only appear on a node's "full" page view. This option is also customizable, however, so that the button(s)
>     will show up on teasers as well.